# Listing objects in Java

Tags: java, class, object

I'm new to Java so my apologies if this is a stupid question. I'm looking for a way to list all the objects in a class from another class so I don't need to add them to a list as they are created. The idea is then I would be able to use e.g. 
for(objects : class) 
    {//do something} 
but I can't find a way to get a list of them.

Does anyone know of a way to do this if it is possible?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)?

Comment: Basically `objects of another class`..what it means?? show some code ex

Comment: Do you mean the _fields_ of the class or do you mean its _instances_?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question and give an example.

Comment: Can't find anything in reflection to help, I have no code examples as I don't know how to write it but I basically want to create a list of all instances (yeah instances sorry) in a class. I'm writing a practice code of a bank account and I want to list all the instances names from within another class without making a list as I input them. Sorry, not very clear I know.

Comment: You should rethink this.  I see no reason to expose all the private state from any object just so another object can interact with it.

Comment: I know it's a bad way to do it but I just wanted to see if it was possible as part of learning.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not support itself. But you can implement your own mechanism.
Below is sample code. I hope this is not requirement for any production level code. Because below code will hold references to all the objects and they won't be eligible for garbage collection and may lead to memory leak for high volumes of instances

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld
{
  private static final List<HelloWorld> list = new ArrayList<>();

  public HelloWorld(){
    list.add(this);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    HelloWorld object = new HelloWorld();
    System.out.print(list.size());
  }
}
```